# Como criar um arquivo .desktop confiável no Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aplicação-desktop

Tenho o seguinte arquivo .desktop para abrir um arquivo em `Python`, ele está funcionando, mas toda as vezes antes de executar abre uma caixa de diálogo dizendo que o lançador de aplicativo não é confiável, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo Desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Classificador
Type=Application
Exec=/home/projeto/app.py
Terminal=false
```

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: O ambiente gráfico é Gnome, correto? Não sei se isso de fato influencia, mas talvez possa haver alguma distinção no caso do kde...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso acontece por que o atalho não tem permissões de execução, isso vale tanto para o Gnome quanto para o KDE pelo o que sei

Você pode atribuir permissão de execução com o `chmod` e com o parâmetro +x

Ex.: `chmod +x arquivo.desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Eu já havia marcado como executável, porém dava a mesma mensagem de aplicativo não confiável. O que resolveu para mim foi copiar o lançador para a pasta /usr/share/applications